# VBA Add Condition to row deletion

Tags: vba, excel

I am putting the final touches on a macro code however the last bit of line I have included is used to delete rows where data in column A is blank. When I have a situation where there would be blank rows it works fine however if there is no need for a row deletion I am having a debugging issue. How can I change my code posted below to work only when there are extra blank rows based on no information in column A and work the same when there is no need for deletion.

```
Range("A7:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Wrap in `On Error Resume Next` then `On Error Goto 0` to ignore any errors due to there being no blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Count the blank rows in the range first and if there is then execute the delete code, otherwise just pass:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A1:A" & LastRow)) > 0 Then
    Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Tim Williams suggestion will also work, but I am not a fan of using `On error resume next` since if by any chance you develop your code more and more and you forget to keep the wrapper intact, then you may get into problems. Plus, if there is no blank cells/rows to delete, you may want to execute some other code, which in that case `on error resume next` will not be handy.

Comment: @HazatBangurah please hit the check mark to select this as the correct answer